# Network booting a Mac OS install image

Tags: mac, boot, pxe

I've got a HP Mini 1000 that I'm attempting to turn into a Hackintosh.

At the moment I don't have an external drive handy, so I'm trying to be clever.

Basically, is there some way to take a bootable CD image of Mac OS X and use it to boot over the network?  I can get PXE to boot into WindowsPE just fine.

---

Come to think of it, if there's just some way to take a bootable disk and use it for network booting that would work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://web.archive.org/web/20090626001248/http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090317042911165) might work, although it's not very easy. However, it would be much easier to just use a normal USB stick that's large enough to hold the image; you can find out more about this [here](http://www.maciverse.com/install-boot-os-x-leopard-from-a-usb-flash-drive.html).

As a side note, the steps used to manage installing from a USB stick or from the network drive in no way break the Mac OS X EULA or any other laws.

Comment: Again. Well answered :) You seem to slip past that EULA thing quite well.

Comment: Well, what can I say? I have a thing for EULAs, especially the Mac OS one. Why do you think I was so interested in this? :)

Comment: The first link is now dead. Found it in the WayBack Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20090626001248/http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090317042911165

Comment: @Nulano thanks, updated the answer with the new link.